# Get all permissions provided by given module via hook_permission()

Tags: drupal-7

How to list all permissions enabled by given module(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be over simplifying the solution but to retrieve the permissions of a module you only need to execute the modules hook_permissions. e.g. call views_permission()

If your looking for all the permissions in the system then you can try calling [user_permission_get_modules](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_permission_get_modules/7)() which is part of the user module in core.

```php
/**
 * Determine the modules that permissions belong to.
 *
 * @return
 *   An associative array in the format $permission => $module.
 */
function user_permission_get_modules() {
  $permissions = array();
  foreach (module_implements('permission') as $module) {
    $perms = module_invoke($module, 'permission');
    foreach ($perms as $key => $value) {
      $permissions[$key] = $module;
    }
  }
  return $permissions;
}
```